# php table of values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a table of values like this:

http://www.conversiontable.org/clothingsizeconversiontable.html

and I want to declare these values in a php class and then manipulate them easily.

In your opinion, what is the best way to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an array indexed by country name and then by size number:

```
$country_sizes = array(
    'United States' => array(6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18),
    ...
)
```

But in order to avoid mistakes and make the code more readable, I would assign a label to each size type. Then I would build an array indexed *by size type first*, and then by country:

```
$sizes = array(
    'S' => array(
        'United States' => 6,
        'United Kingdom' => 28,
        ...
    ),
    'M' => array(
        'United States' => 8,
        'United Kingdom' => 30,
        ...
    ),
    ...
);
```

This second way is more tedious to build, but seems more natural to me (what's the S size in U.K.?). Anyway, it's your choice according to your needs ;)

Comment: the problem is that the admin of the site doesn;t introduce only one type of sizes. he may introduce any type of size, and the conversion must be done automatically. so if i declare like in the previous example, i must make a huge vector

Comment: What do you mean with "any type of size"? I thought the sizes followed a standard :p Being that the case I understand that the sizes data is dynamic, so I would try a database-based approach rather than plain arrays. Maybe you can improve your question by adding more information

Comment: yep. they are stored in the database (the values if the array). i guess i 'll try using the second approach, but with more dimensions: something like:

        'women' => array(
   'coats_dresses_suits' => array(   
          'US' => 6,
          'UK' => 28,
     'CONTINENTAL'=>34,

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
$sizes = array(
  'United States' => array(6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18),
  'United Kingdom' => array (28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40)
);

echo('United states first size: ' . $sizes['United States'][0]);
```